# PostgreSQL Partition range - strange behaviour

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm partitioning a table (t1) using an integer range using the check like this:

```
CONSTRAINT t1_201611_check CHECK (date_id >= 20161101 AND date_id <= 20161130)
CONSTRAINT t1_201612_check CHECK (date_id >= 20161201 AND date_id <= 20161231)
```

so on..

It works fine and search in the right partitioned table when I execute the following query:

```
select * from t1
where date_id >= 20161201
and date_id <= 20161231;
```

But, when I execute the following query, for some reason it search the information in all partitioned tables:

```
select * from t1
where date_id >= to_char('2016-12-01'::date, 'YYYYMMDD')::int
and date_id <= to_char('2016-12-31'::date, 'YYYYMMDD')::int;
```

I think PostgreSQL does something wrong when it receives a function in the where clause, am I right?

How can I change this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ability of the system to limit to a specific partition is known as "constraint exclusion" (right now, Postgres doesn't have a built-in concept of "partitions", just the pieces you need to build them).

The important thing to understand is that this mechanism is built into the *query planner*. If you run `EXPLAIN ...` on your query, you will see nodes in the plan for scanning each child table (partition).

What "constraint exclusion" does is delete those nodes if the constraints on the child table mean it cannot possibly contain any relevant rows. *This all happens before the query is executed*.

Now, the problem with your second query is that the planner doesn't know what the value of `to_char('2016-12-01'::date, 'YYYYMMDD')::int` is - it hasn't run the function yet. (You and I know from looking at it that it's equivalent to the constant value `20161201`, but that's a complex leap of logic for a compiler like Postgres's query planner!) So it can't prove that no rows will be returned from any particular table in order to exclude them.

At the bottom of [the manual page on partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html), there is this tip:

> Keep the partitioning constraints simple, else the planner may not be able to prove that partitions don't need to be visited. Use simple equality conditions for list partitioning, or simple range tests for range partitioning, as illustrated in the preceding examples. A good rule of thumb is that partitioning constraints should contain only comparisons of the partitioning column(s) to constants using B-tree-indexable operators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I thought the problem was the fact that to_char is not an IMMUTABLE function..
That's clear now!

Comment: Do you have any idea why in the following example the query planner is not searching inside all tables? Just in the right table?

     `select * from t1
     where date_id >= replace('2017-01-01', '-', '')::integer
     and date_id <= replace('2017-01-01', '-', '')::integer;`

Comment: @LeandroGuimarães Well, the documentation says "the planner *may* not be able to prove ..."; not "*will* not..."; so evidently in some cases, it *can* pre-compute the constant value and match it to the constraint, but there's no guarantee that it will do so. The query planner is an extremely complex piece of software, and the exact cases that work probably vary between versions as the code is improved in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you need computed parameters then build it dinamically:

```
create or replace function f(_start_date date, _end_date date)
returns setof t1 as $f$

begin
    return query execute $$ 
        select *
        from t1
        where date_id >= $1 and date_id <= $2
    $$ using to_char(_start_date, 'YYYYMMDD')::int, to_char(_end_date, 'YYYYMMDD')::int
    ;
end;

$f$ language plpgsql;

select *
from f('2016-12-01'::date, '2016-12-31'::date);
```